# Got an error reading communication packets in MySQL hosted on Docker containers with master slave replication

Tags: mysql, docker

I have set up a master and 2 slave MySQL databases in my `docker-compose.yml`. When starting, they start up fine, but when I run some operations **I get the error**:

> Got an error reading communication packets

in all 3 (master, slave1 and slave2)

Here are the .cnf files for all 3

`master.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
 server-id = 1
 log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
 binlog_do_db = common
 bind-address = 0.0.0.0
 character_set_server = utf8
 collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

`slave-1.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 2
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
binlog_do_db = warehouse_b2b_common
replicate_do_db = warehouse_b2b_common
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

`slave-2.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 3
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
binlog_do_db = warehouse_b2b_common
replicate_do_db = warehouse_b2b_common
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a bad configuration in your binlog_do_db and replicate_do_db. Read this first: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db